# Impala - replace NULL to zero for entire table

Tags: null, impala

Hi experts out there -

Is there anyway to replace null to zero for an entire table in impala?
So far, I've only found coalesce or case - when, which allows me to change column by column..but I have more than 210 + columns in the table so i'm looking for something more efficient if possible..

SELECT COALESCE(table1.column1,0) 
FROM table1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer the general question, if one needs to replace NAs in 200 columns without typing `COALESCE(table1.column1,0)` 200+ times.

But I can see from your profile you probably use R. So do I, and I have the same issue: I need to replace NAs in my table with 200 columns.

My solution is to use implyr with R.

```
# libraries
library(pacman)
p_load(implyr
       ,odbc
       ,tidyverse
)

# connect to database
con <- src_impala(drv = odbc::odbc(),
                  HOST="host.xxx.x",
                  PORT=12345,
                  ...)

# connect to table
table1 <- tbl(con,table1)

# get columns with I want to replace NAs in, in my case it's numeric tables
numeric_columns_to_replace_NAs <- table1 %>% 
                                  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
                                  colnames

# the command which replaces all NAs with 0's
query <- table1 %>% 
         mutate_at(.vars = vars(numeric_columns_to_replace_NAs),
                   .funs = funs(coalesce(.,0))) 

# run command - this will print to the console
query
```

you can also `compute()` or `collect()` your results depending on what you need (see [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/implyr/implyr.pdf))

If you need the query in hive, you can extract the code this way:

```
# some object with the class "tbl_impala"
query_object <- query %>% 
              collapse() %>% 
              .[2]

# actual query which can be passed to hive via R. 
sql_query <- query_object[[1]]$x %>% 
           as.character()

# create new table
new_query <- paste0("CREATE TABLE table2 AS ",sql_query) %>% 
           str_replace_all(pattern = "'",replacement = '"') # this cleans up the code so it works

# if you want text without characters like \n in there.
cat(sql_query)
```